# Jquery ajax mysql search based on 2 input fields

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, cgi

I have to 2 input fields with 2 corresponding submit btns in a form. when the user clicks btn1, a table(table1) displays info about input1 (the query is linked to a js file which process ajax call to display table1 - the mysql query is ran by a cgi python script -, the info is passed as a JSON file).  and I have the same set up for input2. both info are processed independently. and this part is working.  BUT now I would like to use input1 as a filter for the search of input2 information in mySQL query.  I initially thought that That I could get the value of input1 in my CGI script for serach2 by inserting:

```
var field1=getvalue(#input1)
```

but this not working. so I probably need to refer to input1 in my js file when I process the ajax call for search2.
here my search2 function:

```
unction runSearch2( term) {                                                  

  $('#table2').empty();                                                     
  $('#table1').empty();                                                     

  // here i used .serialize for input2
  var frmStr = $('#form2 input').serialize();                               

  $.ajax({                                                                  
    url: './cgi_temp2.cgi',                                               
    dataType: 'json',                                                     
    data: frmStr,                                                         
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                          
        processJSON2(data);                                               
    },                                                                    
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){                      
        alert("Failed to perform gene search! textStatus: (" + textStatus$
              ") and errorThrown: (" + errorThrown + ")");                
    }                                                                     
});                                                                                                                                 
}
```

and here my CGI file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3                                                      

import cgi, json                                                              
import os                                                                     
import mysql.connector                                                        

def main():                                                                   
   print("Content-Type: application/json\n\n")                               
   form = cgi.FieldStorage()                                                 
   term2 = form.getvalue('input2')

   #trying here to get the value of input1 (information1_id)                                                           
   #term1=getvalue('input1')                                             

   conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='user1', password='psd1', host='host1'
   cursor = conn.cursor()                                                    

qry = """                                                                 
      SELECT name_input2, age_input2, city_input2                               
      FROM info2                                                          
      join info1 ON                                                    
      info2_id=information1_id                                                  
      WHERE name_input2 LIKE %s and info2_id=%s                       
"""                                                                       
     # adding another query condition based on the value of input1
     cursor.execute(qry, ('%' + term + '%',term1))                             

results = { 'match_count': 0, 'matches': list() }                         
for (name_input2, age_input2, city_input2) in cursor:
    results['matches'].append({'name_input2': name_input2, 'age_input': age_input2,'city_input2':city_input2})
    results['match_count'] += 1                                           

conn.close()                                                              


 #send the value back to the JS file to be display                                                                        
print(json.dumps(results))
```

how do I refer to input1 so I can use it in my mysql query for input2?

Answer (score 0):

If you serialize the input, it will return just that input. You should serialize the whole form, that way you'll get both values in your back end. `getvalue('input1')` doesn't work because you are just not sending that parameter.

Comment: how would you serialize the whole form at once with 2 input fields?

Comment: If your form `form2` contains both fields, it's just `var frmStr = $("#form2").serialize();`. If it does not, just drop the `serialize()` and build the parameters yourself, `var frmStr={input1:$("#input1").val(),input2:$("#input2").val()};` (replace the `#input1` and `#input2` with the correct selectors to reach each field).

Comment: thank you so much... it is working now.. now I need to address the jquery autocomplete feature on input2. but this will be another question probably!